# How can i make a selfstarting script

Tags: command-line, scripts, internet, startup

I have an TL-WN727N wireless adapter connected to my laptop.
Every time I start my laptop I must manually enter those two commands in a terminal:

1. ```
   echo 'install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 5370" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf
   ```
2. ```
   sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
   ```

Is it possible to automatically run those two commands on startup to enable my internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in Ubuntu 14.04.3

You need root privileges to do this, so be careful.

```
sudo su
```

There is several ways to do this, I did something similar to unblock my wireless card when resume.

Just create a script in /etc/init.d/ (name it as you want, I'll name it "wireless")

```
nano /etc/init.d/wireless
```

inside your script, write your commands

```
#!/bin/sh
install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 5370" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf
sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

Save it, CTRL+X then Y (in nano)

Once in the script folder, run

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/wireless
```

And then

```
update-rc.d wireless defaults
```

As I said, there's several ways to do this, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab as one option

1. Goto a terminal
2. Enter `crontab -e` (`e` used for editing, `-l` used for listing)
3. insert the following commands in crontab

`@reboot echo 'install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 5370" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf;sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb`

or prepare a shell script as `/user/home/temp.sh`

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo 'install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 5370" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf;sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

and add this in `crontab -e`

```
    @reboot /user/home/temp.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of doing this is to put the two commands in **etc/rc.local**

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add your lines before the command `exit 0`. So It will be something like,

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo 'install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 5370" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf
modprobe -v rt2800usb
exit 0
```

**Note:** You dont need to put sudo, since the script will be executed as root.
Sometimes you may also need a

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```